# Is a different type of screw preferred for screwing into softwood vs hardwood?

Tags: fasteners

I'm good at accidentally splitting wood. I'm also flummoxed by the variety of screws available for wood working projects. Not wanting to "screw up" some nice hardwood:

Is a different type of screw preferred for screwing into softwood vs hardwood?

Does pitch or thread to shank ratio matter?

Comment: Always predrill the hole, especially for hardwoods.

Comment: If you're worried about splitting the wood, you've got to predrill the screw holes. In general, you drill slightly larger holes in hardwood than in soft. Here's a machinist's guide to drilling for standard slot wood screws: http://www.engineershandbook.com/Tables/woodscrewpilotholes.htm Note that the shank hole size is the same, but the pilot holes are different where it's convenient.